# nodeJS buffer and crypto libraries is giving different answers for different versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, buffer

Im migrating some code from node.v4 to Node.v8

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer
const buf = 
Buffer.from('4DB79D009E6E0F59BC67879BDE67F4CDD9E2582794F80CFFF30321C2BDF85CCD', 'hex');


const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256',  buf.toString('binary'));
hash.update('Hello world');
console.log(hash.digest('base64'));
```

Why is this output different in each version. The node v4 answer is correct, because we have been using it for a number of years.

Comment: If you include the output for each then we could test against other runtimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your code working, I'm not sure if you realized it already or not, but simply use the raw buffer.

```
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256',  buf);
```

In the crypto library it mentions

> This is here because many functions accepted binary strings without
>   any explicit encoding in older versions of node, and we don't want
>   to break them unnecessarily.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/449d60df1c11935d50e30bcad2a9ff4f5b4e955b/lib/crypto.js#L30

```
function toBuf(str, encoding) {
  encoding = encoding || 'binary';
  if (typeof str === 'string') {
    if (encoding === 'buffer')
      encoding = 'binary';
    str = new Buffer(str, encoding);
  }
  return str;
}
exports._toBuf = toBuf;
```

Now it's

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/crypto/util.js#L38

```
function toBuf(str, encoding) {
  if (typeof str === 'string') {
    if (encoding === 'buffer' || !encoding)
      encoding = 'utf8';
    return Buffer.from(str, encoding);
  }
  return str;
}
```

for hmac, `toBuf` is only ever called with key, so if encoding is `undefined` and you supply a string then previously you get `new Buffer(str,"binary")` whereas now you get `Buffer.from(str,"utf8")`

The following commit mentions these changes, I'm not sure why the comment was left the same but with utf replaced. https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/b010c8716498dca398e61c388859fea92296feb3

Comment: So the fix is simply to remove `.toString('binary')` and use a buffer directly?

Comment: Yes, but that was not the question, however, I have included it at the beginning of this answer as an edit.